# Who was first to show that the first nine of the ten plagues could be grouped into three groups of three?

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, plagues-makkos, shemot-exodus, exodus

Who was first to show that the first nine of the ten plagues could be grouped into three groups of three?

1. The First Plague: Water Turned to Blood דָּם (7:17-24; 7:17-24)
   Go to Pharoah – לֵ֣ךְ אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֞ה
2. The Second Plague: Frogs צְפַרְדֵּעַ (7:25-11; 7:25-15)
   Go to Pharaoh – בֹּ֖א אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֑ה
3. The Third Plague: Gnats/Lice כֵּן  (8:12-15; 8:16-19)
   **No pre-announcement to Pharaoh** – The magicians … they could not. הַחַרְטֻמִּ֧ים ...‬ וְלֹ֣א יָכֹ֑לוּ – This is the finger of God! – אֶצְבַּ֥ע אֱלֹהִ֖ים הִ֑וא
4. The Fourth Plague: Flies/Insects עָרֹב (8:16-28; 8:20-32)
   present yourself to Pharaoh – וְהִתְיַצֵּב֙ לִפְנֵ֣י פַרְעֹ֔ה
5. The Fifth Plague: Egyptian Livestock Die בָּקָר (9:1-7; 9:1-7)
   – Go to Pharaoh – בֹּ֖א אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֑ה
6. The Sixth Plague: Boils שְׁחִין (9:8-12; 9:8-12)
   **No pre-announcement to Pharaoh** – magicians were unable – וְלֹֽא־יָכְל֣וּ הַֽחַרְטֻמִּ֗ים
7. The Seventh Plague: Hail בָּרָ֖ד (9:13-35; 9:13-35)
   present yourself to Pharaoh – וְהִתְיַצֵּ֖ב לִפְנֵ֣י פַרְעֹ֑ה
8. The Eighth Plague: Locusts אַרְבֶּ֖ה (10:1-20; 10:1-20) – Go to Pharaoh - בֹּ֖א אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֑ה
9. The Ninth Plague: Darkness חֹ֖שֶׁךְ (10:21-29; 10:21-29)
   **No pre-announcement to Pharaoh**
10. A Final Plague בְּכֹור֮
    I will not see your face again. – לֹא־אֹסִ֥ף עֹ֖וד רְאֹ֥ות פָּנֶֽיךָ

Comment: Probably someone before recorded history. It's pretty obvious, no?

Comment: Double AA: Thus, you say it was understood as such from when first written.

Comment: I didn't say that, though it is a plausible timeline.

Comment: Don Isaac Abarbanel

Answer (score 5):

According to many commentators (esp. [Maharal](https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem.57.2?lang=bi&with=Navigation&lang2=en)), this was the intent of [Rabbi Yehudah](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_The_Ten_Plagues.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) when he broke the plagues into three groups in his mnemonic:

> רַבִּי יְהוּדָה הָיָה נוֹתֵן בָּהֶם סִמָּנִים: דְּצַ"ךְ עַדַ"שׁ בְּאַחַ"ב.
> Rabbi Yehuda was accustomed to giving [the plagues] mnemonics: Detsakh [the Hebrew initials of the first three plagues], Adash [the Hebrew initials of the second three plagues], Beachav [the Hebrew initials of the last four plagues].

The last plague stands on its own after the three sets of three ([Maharal ad loc.](https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem.57.11?lang=en&with=Navigation&lang2=en)), so it gets tacked onto the end of the last set.

Comment: Why does a plague that stands on its own get attached to something else? That's inherently contradictory.

Comment: [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.9.14?p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.9.14.1) treats the last 4 as a set, not 3 with an extra tacked on. @DoubleAA

Comment: @n.t see the Gur Aryeh on that Rashi (written by the Maharal!)

Comment: @Heshy It looks like the Maharal contradicts himself, at first glance. That still doesn't negate what he said in Gevuros Hashem from answering OP's question.